# Spring Data MongoDB wants to connect to a database in test scope

Tags: spring, mongodb

Java project built with maven. When you add the dependency to spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb, it will try to connect to a database with default settings (localhost, port 27017, etc) during the test phase of the build. Is there a way to suppress this behaviour? This will happen even if you have no code actually trying to interact with the database in the tests. It does not affect the build, but prints annoying exception in the build log.

To recreate: Build a barebone Spring-application using for instance Spring Initializr, add the dependency for spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb, run a build and watch the build log for exceptions.

Sample POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

From the build output:

```
13:40:15.551 [cluster-ClusterId{value='64ca409f5fb52846dda0f121', description='null'}-localhost:27017] [26] INFO  org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:27017
com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:73) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.8.2.jar:?]
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:183) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.8.2.jar:?]
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.lookupServerDescription(DefaultServerMonitor.java:198) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.8.2.jar:?]
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:158) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.8.2.jar:?]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[?:?]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method) ~[?:?]
at sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672) ~[?:?]
at sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:549) ~[?:?]
at sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:597) ~[?:?]
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327) ~[?:?]
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633) ~[?:?]
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:107) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.8.2.jar:?]
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.initializeSocket(SocketStream.java:82) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.8.2.jar:?]
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:68) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.8.2.jar:?]
```

I have looked over the configuration parameters for MongoDB and I cannot see any ways to modify this. I'm also aware that this behaviour could possibly be altered in specific SpingBootTests using configuration exclusion, but the question is if theres a way to disable this behaviour "globally"?

Comment: When you create a project from scratch you get a single test created for you.  This is a spring-boot test and will attempt to spin up the spring context.  Since you have added mongo, it's going to try to create a connection to it.  Either add the properties to satisfy the connection to preferably an in-memory mongo instance for testing, or add an exclusion to your test to exclude the monogo autoconfiguration.  You'll notice that this test still passes, it's just outputs that stack trace because it cannot connect.

Comment: Thanks, Lane. Just thought there would be a way to tell it to go "testmode", as I have the db mocked for tests :) Thanks again.